# set a queue to run jobs one at a time

Tags: laravel, queue, horizon

in my application i have a route that get a big array of objects and chunk it  to smaller parts (for example 250 rows in each part) and push every part to the queue. but this data must process row by row and each job must run only after the previous one is done. because every row depend on some of rows before itself

my queue driver is redis and horizon and it execute jobs very fast.
I tried to use later method and set a dynamic delay. but it doesnt solve my problem. because the client might cant handle big data and splits its data (paginate it) and send them to  my api. and so the data in each request must add to the end of the queue.

for now i add each part three time to the queue like below. but im looking for a better way

```
foreach ($dataParts as $i => $dataPart) {
    Queue::later((($i * 5)), new ImportData($dataPart));
    Queue::later((($i * 60) ), new ImportData($dataPart));
    Queue::later((($i * 120)), new ImportData($dataPart));
}
```

Comment: I think you want either a batch job (and batch everything togheter in order) or use events. When a job is done, you know which one should go next, and trigger another event when that one is done, and you repeat...

Answer (score 0):

I tried job batching but still didn't solve my problem. then tried withoutOverlaping method and that didn't work too.

finally i added a new worker and queue in horizon.php file and set `maxProcess => 1` for it. and push my jobs to that. and worked as i wanted

horizon.php:

```
...
...
...

'defaults' => [
        // the default queue
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 1,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],

         // new queue process only one job at a time
        'supervisor-single' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['single-queue'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'maxProcesses' => 1,
            'memory' => 128,
            'tries' => 1,
            'nice' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

in controller:

```
foreach ($dataParts as $dataPart) {
    Queue::push(new ImportData($dataPart), null, 'single-queue');
}
```